# How to make fmt:setLocale work on fmt:formatNumber with only language code in JSP?

Tags: jsp, internationalization, jstl, stripes

I'm trying to localize currency on my JSP web application, problem is when I ask for locale, I only get language code ("en") instead of full language and country code ("en_US").
Problem with this is, formatNumber doesnt work when setLocale's value doesn't contain language and country code.

I can solve it by checking for locale language at the beginning of the jsp page and setting default country code for few languages and then setting value of setLocale, but this method looks pretty ugly to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

This is how I do it now:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${pageContext.response.locale == 'cs'}">
        <f:setLocale value="cs_CZ" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <f:setLocale value="en_US" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<f:formatNumber type="currency" value="${product.price}" currencyCode="CZK"/>
```

Comment: how are you setting the locale currently.

Comment: He doesn't have to!  Stripes does it!  Yaay for Stripes!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currency is dependent on the country, not on the language. You really need to set it as well. A more generic way is to use a `Filter` for this so that you don't need to copypaste the check in every JSP.

**Update**: I now see that you're using [`HttpServletResponse#getLocale()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getLocale%28%29) which returns the programmatically set locale or otherwise the container's default locale. The normal practice is to use [`HttpServletRequest#getLocale()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29) to get the client's locale, thus so:

```
${pageContext.request.locale}
```

See if that helps. You however still need to check if the country is actually present. A `Filter` is the best place for that.

Comment: Firefox only sends language code afaik. Is there some workaround?

Comment: That's fully client-controlled (browser settings and so on), you can't do much with it.

Answer (score 4):

You're using Stripes!!  Stripes will handle the locale for you, and you should be getting it from the ActionBeanContext:

```
<c:set var='curLocale' value='${actionBean.context.locale}'/>
```

Don't go around Stripes' back!  That is the path to distress and unhapiness!  Stripes is your friend!

In general, you should not need to use `<fmt:setLocale>` because Stripes *already sets up the locale in the Stripes filter.* Again, *Stripes is your friend!!* Read about this in the Stripes wiki:

http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Localization

Comment: Does it also worry about the locale country? It is namely **mandatory** to display currencies. If so, that would the way to go. If not, then you would still need a custom filter which checks/sets the locale country.

Comment: The stripes locale filter picks up the locale preference from the HTTP header (ie, from the browser), and then tries to match it against a configured server-side list of locale strings. Yes, the locale strings include country code.  If the browser just says "en", then Stripes will match that against the first "en" locale on the server, but would use whatever the server had for "country" as the default.

Comment: That's then indeed the way to go. +1.

Comment: I know stripes is my friend, but actionBean.context.locale returns only "en", that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Well have you configured the complete list of locales that your server can support?  If you put both "cs_CZ" and "en_US" in the "LocalePicker.locales" init param in web.xml, then I think it should pick up the complete locale string for you.